# Automatically segment and align the QR from the given image

Tags: image-processing

everyone

I need a python or a Matlab code to automatically segment the QR from an image. Then, correct its
alignment so that its three corners aligned to top right, top left, and bottom right.

[The left images are samples of input while the right images are the required output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ihlru.png)

This is my code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils

# Load imgae, grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('Case3/3.3.bmp') #read the image
original = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #convert image to gray 
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (9,9), 0) # Bluring (smothing)  
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]  # Convert image to binary 

# Morph close (performed on binary images)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5)) # Draw rec 
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=2)#closing
    

# Find contours and filter for QR code
cnts = cv2.findContours(closing, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.04 * peri, True)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    ar = w / float(h)
    if len(approx) == 4 and area > 1000 and (ar > .85 and ar < 1.3):
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 3)
        ROI = original[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('close', closing)
cv2.imshow('image', image)

cv2.waitKey()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this tutorial using [ZBar Library](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/): [Tutorial-Link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/21/an-opencv-barcode-and-qr-code-scanner-with-zbar/)

Comment: I need a code that uses Segmentation, Line Hough transform, Morphological operations, or/and Region properties. 
Not a build-in function.

Comment: Is it possible to detect the 3 square/rectangles at the corners of the QR code?